# Notation for an eigenspace?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The set of $\lambda$ satisfying
$$
(A - \lambda I_n)\vec{x} = 0
$$
is called the eigenspace of a matrix $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$.

Now I want to write eigenspace = the set of eigenvalues $\lambda$ satisfying ... as a set. So I want to use notation like $\lambda_A$ or $E_A$ or even better, $A_{\lambda}$ as candidates for my set but I am not sure. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.cliffsnotes.com/math/algebra/linear-algebra/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors/eigenspaces

Comment: Do you want to express the set of the eigenvalues or the space their associated eigenvectors span?

Comment: @Tristen: The span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of eigenvalues is not an Eigenspace (set of eigenvectors for a particular eigenvalue, plus $\vec 0$), but rather the [spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_matrix), which you can denote $\sigma_A$.

Your question asks for the set of eigenvalues, but your comment asks for the span of the eigenvectors, which you could call $E_\lambda$ or $E_\lambda(A)$ as in the Cliff's Notes page Amzoti linked.